# Java - load data into a Singleton when it is accessed, but only after time has passed

Tags: java

I have a singleton that contains some data I want to cache from a database. I'd like it to call the database and refresh its data every time it is accessed AND a certain amount of time has passed. The singleton pattern I used was the enum one from Effective Java. What do you think is the best way to accomplish this? Ideally, I would override some method that is called every time MySingleton.INSTANCE is called...but I don't know if such a method exists. Another idea is to include a call to the refresh method within every method that can be accessed by the client code...but this seems clumsy to me.

Comment: Search for "implementation of cache"?

Comment: `long lastAccessTime = System.currentMilisTime();` and `if (System.currentMilisTime() > yourTimeout + lastAccessTime) { //load data from database; }`

Comment: Using a singleton to cache a database seems clumsy to me, but it may be a reasonable compromise to make.

Comment: What's the point of caching if you refresh it every time it is accessed?

Comment: @proskor He's not refreshing every time it's accessed. Only if it's been `x` time since last accessed.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi @proskor, the idea is like crush posted...it only refreshes if it has been long enough AND it then gets accessed. This is because it might get accessed a lot (thousands of times) in a small period of time and during that time, the data doesn't need refreshed. But sometimes minutes or longer might go by when no one accesses it, and during that time I don't want a timer running just to refresh the data every so often, I'd rather have the system free for other tasks...so thus it loaded only after it is accessed AND it has been long enough that the data has gone stale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of accessing the INSTANCE directly you can use

```
DataCache.getInstance().method();
```

The `getInstance()` can check if the data needs to be refreshed.

Comment: And you wouldn't have to worry about synchronization if you created a new Singleton instance when your data is refreshed.

Comment: @crush +1 it's not really a singleton any more, but it is a better idea.

Comment: I am liking this idea...the only other thing I would need is to make sure no one can call DataCache.INSTANCE which wouldn't make the refresh check...do you think I could make the enum a private inner class of some wrapper that only provides getInstance() as a public method?

Comment: Wouldn't just making `INSTANCE` private do?

Comment: It would but when I tried that, the compiler tells me "Illegal modifier for the enum constant INSTANCE; no modifier is allowed."

Comment: Personally, I would allow the developer to skip the refresh check if you really wanted to.  Otherwise you have to use a normal class to make `INSTANCE` private.

Answer (score 1):

For such a scenario, a robust, performant and very well tested solution is a Caching Library like EHCache: http://ehcache.org/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you need is a **time-based eviction cache.**
Take a look at [Google Guava Cache library:](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Timed_Eviction)

> CacheBuilder provides two approaches to timed eviction:
>
> - **expireAfterAccess(long duration, TimeUnit unit)** Only expire entries after the specified duration has passed since the entry was last accessed by a read or a write. Note that the order in which entries are evicted will be similar to that of size-based eviction.
> - **expireAfterWrite(long duration, TimeUnit unit)** Expire entries after the specified duration has passed since the entry was created, or the most recent replacement of the value. This could be desirable if cached data grows stale after a certain amount of time.

So which approach do you need? You said:

> I'd like it to call the database and refresh its data every time it is accessed AND **a certain amount of time has passed.**

A certain amount of time has passed since when?

- Since entry was last read from your cache? It doesn't matter how much time has passed since entry was loaded from database? Then use **expireAfterAccess()**
- Since entry was last loaded from database into your cache? Then use **expireAfterWrite()**

You can even use them both at the same time.
Here is such example: http://mkorytin.blogspot.com/2012/02/caching-objects-with-guava.html